# Resize div into original div with child resize

Tags: jquery

Suppose my div has left:26px and top:26px, after I apply a resize a div into 2551*2551 the above top and left positions no more point to the old positions. Now how can we calculate the new top and left for the resized div which are equivalent to the left and top positions of  div after resized.

Comment: Why don't you use some percentage values for left and top propeties?

Comment: It would help to show your code. At the moment it's hard to know which div is being resized, and what exactly you mean by eg "old positions"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Ravimca/w1L0ft2a/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Ravimca/w1L0ft2a/3/